# Python string formatting special characters

Tags: python, string-formatting

How do you make the following code work?

```
example = "%%(test)%" % {'test':'name',}
print example
```

Where the desired output is "%name%"

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative is to use the new [Advanced String Formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

```
>>> example = "%{test}%".format(test="name")
>>> print example
%name%
```

Answer (score 5):

```
example = "%%%(test)s%%" % {'test':'name',}
print example
```

`%(key)s` is a placeholder for a string identified by `key`. `%%` escapes `%` when using the `%` operator.

Comment: Ah I knew it would be simple! I tried the classic backslash to cancel special characters then got stuck. Thanks!

Comment: You omitted the helpful reference information: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations.